# How to setup a property from 1 linq2sql obj that is populated by a relationship to another obj

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, orm

I'm using Linq2SQL and I'm pretty new to it.

I've got a User table and a UserData table, the idea being that properties for the User object can be added / removed by adding or removing rows in the UserData table.  I did not come up with this particular design but I am more or less stuck with it (as long as I can come up with a solution)

[alt text http://www.86th.org/linq2sqlproblem.jpg](http://www.86th.org/linq2sqlproblem.jpg)

I'd like to populate/bind "FirstName" on the User object by something along the lines of setting the value to:

```
UserData.Value WHERE UserData.ItemID == User.UserID AND KeyName = 'FirstName'
```

Similarly, LastName would be:

```
UserData.Value WHERE UserData.ItemID == User.UserID AND KeyName = 'LastName'
```

Description of the UserData Table:

- UserData.ItemID is the FK (User.UserID)
- UserData.KeyName is specifying the name of the property
- UserData.Value is the actual value.

How would I setup my User object to handle this so I could do the normal CRUD functionality on this object and have the changes carry through to both tables?

<s>Is this even possible?</s>

Is this bad form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick Note

I renamed *UserData* to *ExtendedProperty* and this caused the relationship from *User* to *ExtendedProperty* to be called *ExtendedProperties*.

### Summary of changes

1. Created a getter/setter for both *FirstName* and *LastName* in the partial *User* class
2. Grabbed the correct *ExtendedProperty* element out of the *ExtendedProperties* collection and either returned or updated the *Value* property of it.
3. Refactored into a reusable format as shown below

```
partial class User
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return (string)this.getExtendedProperty("FirstName").Value; }
        set { this.getExtendedProperty("FirstName").Value = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return (string)this.getExtendedProperty("LastName").Value; }
        set { this.getExtendedProperty("LastName").Value = value; }
    }

    // Grab a related property out of the collection, any changes to it will be reflected in the database after a submit
    private ExtendedProperty getExtendedProperty(string KeyName)
    {
        // grab the properties that fit the criterea
        var properties = (from prop in this.ExtendedProperties where prop.KeyName == KeyName select prop);

        // return value
        ExtendedProperty property = properties.SingleOrDefault();

        // if this is a new user then there arent going to be any properties that match
        if (property == null)
        {
            // Define a new item to add to the collection
            property = new ExtendedProperty()
            {
                ItemID = this.UserID,
                KeyName = KeyName,
                Value = String.Empty
            };

            // Add the item we're about to return to the collection
            this.ExtendedProperties.Add(property);
        }

        // either way we have a valid property to return at this point
        return property;
    }
}
```

I just hope this isn't bloated / grossly inefficient.

### Edit

In *getExtendedProperty*, it would error when setting the *FirstName* or *LastName* of a newly created *User* because it would not have any corresponding *ExtendedProperty* elements in the *ExtendedProperties* collection as shown below.

```
User expected = new User();
expected.UserID = Guid.NewGuid();
expected.UserName = "LJ";
expected.FirstName = "Leeroy";  // It would error here
expected.LastName = "Jenkins";
```

Because of this I added a check to ensure that new items get added to the *ExtendedProperties* collection if they are requested and not currently in there.

I also removed *setExtendedProperty* since I felt it wasn't necessary and was just a method around a 1 liner anyway.

I would really appreciate any feedback before I accept this answer, I'll let it sit for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I feel its bad form but I suppose everyone has there way of doing things. Why can't you assign userdata in the users table? I think I might not be understanding the design idea here.

Comment: The main reason why I cant is because I am phasing out horribly old code and introducing linq to sql as an ORM, meaning I have to abide by the same schema and design as the old objects.  Ideally, yes, I would just assign user data in the users table

Comment: ouch, that sucks man, but I now understand why you need to be able to do it like this. good luck! Hope the rest of the system isn't in a similar state!